# Yii2 schema scans ALL_OBJECTS and not USER_OBJECTS?

Tags: php, oracle, yii, yii2

Why does Yii2 Scan the schema using ALL_OBJECTS and then filters by OWNER = "owner_name" and not by just scanning the USER_OBJECTS?

For some reason that query when scanning ALL_OBJECTS takes a long execution time (45 seconds), when querying USER_OBJECTS it takes around 2 seconds. (production environment)

```
SELECT
    A.COLUMN_NAME,
    A.DATA_TYPE,
    A.DATA_PRECISION,
    A.DATA_SCALE,
    A.DATA_LENGTH,
    A.NULLABLE,
    A.DATA_DEFAULT,
    COM.COMMENTS AS COLUMN_COMMENT
FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS A
    INNER JOIN ALL_OBJECTS B ON B.OWNER = A.OWNER AND LTRIM(B.OBJECT_NAME) = LTRIM(A.TABLE_NAME)
    LEFT JOIN ALL_COL_COMMENTS COM ON (A.OWNER = COM.OWNER AND A.TABLE_NAME = COM.TABLE_NAME AND A.COLUMN_NAME = COM.COLUMN_NAME)
WHERE
    A.OWNER = 'owner_name'
    AND B.OBJECT_TYPE IN ('TABLE', 'VIEW', 'MATERIALIZED VIEW')
    AND B.OBJECT_NAME = 'object_name'
ORDER BY A.COLUMN_ID
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between accessing `ALL_*`views/synonyms and `USER_*` views/synonym.

`ALL_OBJECTS` describes all objects accessible to the current use whereas `USER_OBJECTS` only lists the objects belong to current user.

Comment: But as it is already connecting as a specific user why not access the USER_* ?, I'm not too keen with regards to databases and oracle in specific, just trying to understand the reason behind this logic of the framework.